# Overlay multiple workspace in ROS2 Foxy

Tags: ros, ros2, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!

I'm less than average in ROS and pretty noob in ROS2 :)

I want to play a little bit with some packages in Foxy and after several install due to some n00bs error I want to build more workspaces in order to limit the damage.

I have these workspaces:
ros2_ws
turtlebot3_ws
dev_ws

How can I make a package from 'dev_ws' to use a package from 'turtlebot3_ws'?
I've tried several ways to make the overlay but no succes!

thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383080/overlay-multiple-workspace-in-ros2-foxy/) by [Ktysai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41908/ktysai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2021-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you [source](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html#source-the-overlay) (e.g. `. ~/turtlebot3_ws/install/setup.bash`) the workspaces where the dependency is prior to building/running things from your `dev_ws`, it should have the desired effect.

Note that new paths are added to the *front* of the various path variables, so whatever you've sourced most recently will have priority (e.g. if you have a package that you are building from source in one directory, but have also installed using `apt`, sourcing the directory will ensure that the source version will be used).

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2021-07-23**:
A concrete example of this kind of daisy chaining of workspaces can also be seen used in practice from the Dockerfile for the Nav2 project, where both an `underlay` and `overlay` workspace are built one after the other on top of the installed ros folder:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/5c61644651c4eab882b042e073d0f5964f03a501/Dockerfile#L111

**Comment by [Ktysai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41908/ktysai/) on 2021-07-24**:
Thank you!
@**shonigmann**, after bashing my heard against the keyboard I've seen a similar path. The explanations are a cool bonus! :)

@**ruffsl** I have to look more careful at that code, is not that readable for me at the moment.